# Dynamically positioned opening/closing panels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have inline-block buttons in the form of an href, when they are clicked their state changes to tabbed, opens the corresponding panel (div) by unhiding it, untabs other buttons and closes all other panels. My question is how do I make the panels appear under the respective row of buttons. For example on a smaller device only one button may fit on a line while on a desktop 2 or more buttons may fit. The following html works fine for 1 button per line, but if there's more on a line, the panel will open before the 2nd button.

```
<div class="collapsible-panels">
  <a class="whyTabs ylead" href="#">Why Should I Lead?</a>

  <div class="whyTabs ylead">
    <p>If you lead a project you can...</p>
  </div>

  <a class="whyTabs yhelp" href="#">Why Should I Help?</a>

  <div class="whyTabs yhelp">
    <p>If you help with a project you can...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Similarly if I do this the html works perfectly for 2 buttons on a line, but if I resize the page or use a different device and the amount of buttons on the page changes it wont.

```
<div class="collapsible-panels">
  <a class="whyTabs ylead" href="#">Why Should I Lead?</a>
  <a class="whyTabs yhelp" href="#">Why Should I Help?</a>

  <div class="whyTabs ylead">
    <p>If you lead a project you can...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="whyTabs yhelp">
    <p>If you help with a project you can...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

My question is, how can I get these panels to open in the correct place based on the situation. Is there any easy way to do it with CSS? Or will I have to do something with javascript/jquery to figure out the layout of the page and adjust html accordingly? Is there a way to place html in relation to a parent without being outside of the flow?

Here is a full example of my code with only 2 buttons but I imagine you can see the problem I am encountering.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Hide all div containers.
    $('div.collapsible-panels div').css('display', 'inline-block');
    $('div.collapsible-panels div').hide();

    //Append click event to the a element.
    $('div.collapsible-panels a').click(function() {

        //Declare our variables
        var clickedButton = $(this); //jquery object for the clicked button

        var collapsibleGroupClass = "." + clickedButton.attr('class').split(' ')[0]; //Class identifier for the clickedbutton's group of buttons and tabs
        var collapsibleTargetClass = "." + clickedButton.attr('class').split(' ')[1]; //Class identifier for the clickedbutton's tab identifier

        var targetTab = $("div.collapsible-panels div" + collapsibleGroupClass + collapsibleTargetClass); //Jquery object for targetted Tab

        var tabbedButton = $("div.collapsible-panels a.tabbed" + collapsibleGroupClass); //Jquery object for tabbed button
        var openTab = $("div.collapsible-panels div.open" + collapsibleGroupClass); //Jquery object for opened tab
        var openTargetTab = $("div.collapsible-panels div" + collapsibleGroupClass + collapsibleTargetClass + ".open"); //Jquery object for open targetted tab

        /**
         *Stop all previous animations
         *clear queue of animations
         *end immediately because new
         *animation is coming!
         */
        $('div.collapsible-panels div').stop(true, true);

        //If the no tab or only the target tab is open.
        if (openTab.length == 0 || openTargetTab.length != 0) {

            //Toggle clicked button to tabbed.
            clickedButton.toggleClass('tabbed');

            //Toggle selected tab and open status.
            targetTab.first().slideToggle(100).toggleClass('open');

        //Else (tab besides our target tab are open)
        } else {

            //Toggle tabbed buttons off.
            tabbedButton.toggleClass('tabbed');

            //Toggle clicked button to tabbed.
            clickedButton.toggleClass('tabbed');

            /**
             *Originally chose closing animation with callback,
             *however this has issues with fast and repeated clicks.
             *Tried other options and didn't like how they worked.
             *Decided upon instantly hide closing tabs and speeding
             *up all opening animations.
             */

            //Hide open tabs and remove open class. 
            openTab.hide().toggleClass('open');

            //Toggle target tab and open status
            targetTab.first().slideToggle(100).toggleClass('open');

            //End if/else statement
        }

        //return false to prevent default click event
        return false;

        //End click event
    });

    //End self-initiating function
});
```

```css
.tabs {
  margin: 4%;
  text-align: center;
}
.tabs a {
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  margin: 0px;
  background: #CE1F24;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: solid 1px #C00000;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
.tabs a:hover {
  background: #B80000;
  border: solid 1px #880000;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
}
.tabs a:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.tabs a.tabbed {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: #587CAF;
  border: solid 1px #587CAF;
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
}
.tabs a:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: #587CAF;
  border: solid 1px #587CAF;
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
}
.tabs div.yanswer {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 60px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  background: #FFF;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border: solid 4px #587CAF;
  z-index: 10;
}
.tabs div.yanswer p {
  font-size: 3em;
  width: auto;
}
.tabs div.yanswer ul {
  font-size: 1.3em;
}
.tabs div.yanswer p.smallfont {
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="collapsible-panels tabs">

  <a class="whyTabs ylead" href="#">Why Should I Lead?</a>

  <div class="whyTabs ylead yanswer">
    <p>If you lead a project you can...</p>
    <br>
    <ul>
      <li>Show management what you can do.</li>
      <li>Make decisions.</li>
      <li>Add to your resume.</li>
      <li>*Earn money or time off.*</li>
    </ul>
    <br>
    <p class="smallfont">*eligible for Tasks with 6+ week turnarounds</p>
  </div>

  <a class="whyTabs yhelp" href="#">Why Should I Help?</a>

  <div class="whyTabs yhelp yanswer">
    <p>If you help with a project you can...</p>
    <br>
    <ul>
      <li>Show management what you can do.</li>
      <li>Learn something new.</li>
      <li>Help make decisions.</li>
      <li>Add to your resume.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve what I wanted I ended up using JS to dynamically build the page. I used some simple jquery to check the width of the page

```
function checkWidth() {
    var windowsize = $(window).width();
    return windowsize;
}
```

Then using this info I decided how many panels should be in each row.
I then built the page with that info keeping track of how many panels I have made, how many I need to make, and inserting the drop down html each time my panels created is divisible by the panelsperRow. I also had to ensure I had the drop down info if the panel created was the last panel to be created.

There was no simple way of doing this with css.